# Issue in Regex match is C# greedy technique

Tags: c#, regex

I have doubt in  below code which doesn't match regular expression:

```
 string strToCheck = "Rahul Chaudhary";
            Regex objAlphaPattern = new Regex("Rah* Chaudhary");
            if (objAlphaPattern.IsMatch(strToCheck)){
                Console.WriteLine(strToCheck);
            }
```

But, when i change

```
Regex objAlphaPattern = new Regex("Rah* Chaudhary");
```

to

```
Regex objAlphaPattern = new Regex("Rah*");
```

It works.

Please help me with regex to match the complete string, when my input is Rah* Chaudhary it should match Rahul Chaudhary.

Thanks.

Comment: `Rah* Chaudhary` is not a *regex*, it is a *wildcard* pattern.

Comment: Well, no, it is actually a regex. But probably not the expected one.

Comment: Maybe you'r looking to use something along the lines of: `^Rah\S+\sChaudhary$` for just a single first name, or even `^Rah.*Chaudhary$` for multiple.

Comment: `h*` looks for 0 or more `h` characters. If you want to search for any character, use `.*`. `"Rah.* Chaudhary"` works

Comment: Is there any way to search without using regex , i.e something similar to str.contains.

Comment: Star means : previous char (here 'h' in your case) repeated as many times as possible. Dot means: any char
Rah.* Chaudhary is the correct regex : it matches Rah, then any char repeated as many times as possible, then " Chaudhary"

Comment: Thanks Rah.* works.